# How to create report (RDLC) for Show Image?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to create report (`RDLC`) for Show Image in Wpf. Explain with working examples:

**This code doesn't work:**

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReportViewerWPF\ReportViewerWPF\CustomerReport.rdlc";
reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
string imagePath = @"C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReportViewerWPF\ReportViewerWPF\Penguins - Copy.jpg";
ReportParameter parameter = new ReportParameter("ImagePath", imagePath);
List<ReportParameter> obj = new List<ReportParameter>();
obj.Add(parameter);
reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(obj);

reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: refer the link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-add-and-display-external-Image-in-RDLC-Report-from-code-behind-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: all ready refer  this link .

Comment: Did you tried adding URI instead of file path for imagePath(as given in the link)?

Comment: Yes but No Result Show Blank reportViewer.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing **imagePath** like this,

```
string imagePath=@"file:///C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReportViewerWPF\ReportViewerWPF\Penguins - Copy.jpg"
```

Instead of using **reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh()** use

```
reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

So the whole code will look like this,

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReportViewerWPF\ReportViewerWPF\CustomerReport.rdlc";
reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
string imagePath = @"file:///C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReportViewerWPF\ReportViewerWPF\Penguins - Copy.jpg";
ReportParameter parameter = new ReportParameter("ImagePath", imagePath);
List<ReportParameter> obj = new List<ReportParameter>();
obj.Add(parameter);
reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(obj);
reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Make sure that you are defining Report Parameter correctly in rdlc.

Comment: ssakash Its not Work.

Comment: reportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource ="CustomerReport.rdlc";
           // reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ReportViewerWPF\ReportViewerWPF\CustomerReport.rdlc";
            reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
           
            reportViewer.RefreshReport();

Comment: Above Code Not Show rdlc Report

Comment: Remove processing mode, ReportPath. Assign ReportEmbeddedResource like "ProjectName.CutomerReport.rdlc".

Comment: reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath=@"C:\Users\dsingh\Documents\Visual\rptStudio2012\Projects\CustomerReport.rdlc";                                            reportViewer.RefreshReport();

Comment: First of all, update your questions according to your new approach or solution. Otherwise it's tough to understand code inside comment section. 

Try the updated answer. That should work.

Comment: Print .rdlc Report In Wpf ? Its My Question Using Above Code

Comment: From your main question i assume you are trying to show an image in rdlc report inside wpf app and it's not showing. If you are doing rdlc part correctly like creating parameters, assign parameter value to Image control's source, set source of image to external then above code should work as i tested here.If you are not familiar with rdlc report then start learning that first from basics.

Comment: you can share your project .